# How to simulate timeout response

Tags: python, timeout, simulate

I'm creating a Python script that is always checking if a webapp is ok, because it was usual to send timeout response to several requests.

This script uses httplib:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("10.255.255.1")
conn.request("HEAD", "/")
ping = conn.getresponse()
```

Then simply analyses the http code returned.

I do not control the webapp, so I can't create a endpoint that would return whatever I want, so my question is: How can I simulate that I've received a timeout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate some httplib errors by looking up some of the exceptions at [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) (specifically, look at the *exceptions*).

Very surprisingly, I noticed the timeout it throws is a `socket.timeout`; from a different package. Actually, I discovered this by giving an unrealistically small timeout as argument to `httplib.HTTPConnection` of 0.0001 seconds.

Thus, you can simulate the error by raising the socket.timeout:

```
def requestResultingInTimeout():
    # Pretend to request
    raise socket.timeout
```

Don't forget to `import socket` though.

You might handle it like such:

```
from socket import timeout
try:
    requestResultingInTimeout()
except timeout:
    print("Now that I got a timeout, I'll print this message instead")
```

Answer (score 2):

The more modern approach is to use [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses#exception-as-response-body) library:

Your app:

```
# my_app.py
import requests

def call_some_api(agrs):
    # here prepare request payload/auth
    try:
       response = requests.post(
            'https://some-api.com/path/',
            headers=headers,
            data=payload,
            timeout=60
       )
    except ConnectTimeout as error:
       # handle exception if needed
       return False
    return True
```

Unit tests:

```
# test_my_app.py

import responses

from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout, ConnectTimeout

from my_app import call_some_api

@responses.activate
def test_error_timeout(self):
    """test time-out exception handling"""
    responses.add(
        responses.POST,
        'https://some-api.com/path/',
        body=ConnectTimeout(),
    )
    result = call_some_api(test_agrs) 
    # here is the assertion of the results of your code 
    ...
    assert result == False
```

Do not forget to add `@responses.activate` decorator to tests.